prove for equivalence of $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} {\sqrt[n]{(x+x_1)(x+x_2)\cdots (x+x_n)}}$?
I have used the following equivalence many times, but so far I have not found any proof for it, does anyone know the proof or a reference where this equivalence is stated?
$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty}{\sqrt[n]{(x+x_1)(x+x_2)\cdots(x+x_n)} \sim |x+\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n}{n}|} $ when $n$ is even
$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty}{\sqrt[n]{(x+x_1)(x+x_2)\cdots(x+x_n)} \sim (x+\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n}{n})} $ when $n$ is odd

What do you mean by "equivalence" here? Both of your limits are $\infty$.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Are there any constraints on the sequence $x_n$?

Well, note that
$$
\prod_i (x+x_i) \sim x^n + \left(\sum_i x_i\right)x^{n-1}=x^n\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\sum_i x_i\right)
$$
as $x\rightarrow\infty$... as these are the two highest-order terms in $x$.  Taking the $n$-th root then gets you
$$
x\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{1}{x}\sum_i x_i}\sim x \left(1+\frac{1}{nx}\sum_i x_i\right)=x+\frac{1}{n}\sum_i{x_i}.
$$
Which is what you wanted to show.  You don't need the absolute value signs for even $n$, unless you actually wanted an asymptotic expansion correct for both $x\rightarrow\infty$ and $x\rightarrow-\infty$?

Sorry, I meant $x \to \pm \infty$
